# Position absolute in a @media print class in MVC View

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place elements in the bottom of the page to print but they come to the top when I send it the printer or PDF:

My CSS is:

```
@page 
{
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
    /*page-break-before: always;*/ 
}

@media print 
{
    .page 
    {
        margin: 0;
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        /*page-break-after: always;*/
        position: relative;
    }
}

.lcp-page-number
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}
```

My View:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="lcp-page-number">Página @PageNumber/@PageTotal</div>
</div>
```

In the View, everything is ok, but when I do the print, everything goes to the top of the page, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`.lcp-page-number` is outside your print style block:

```
@media print 
{
    .page 
    {
        margin: 0;
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        /*page-break-after: always;*/
        position: relative;
    }

    /*Needs to be with .page, as you set position:relative only within this print block*/
    .lcp-page-number
    {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but in the HTML View, the element goes to the wrong position, and in the Print version it's going to the top of the page

Comment: What do you mean by HTML View? You mean the webpage? Or the print preview?

Comment: I mean the Webpage, the HTML Page. The Print version it's when you do the print preview for paper ou PDF print